# Swift Package Manager executable app, set deployment target

Tags: swift, macos, swift-package-manager

I'm using Swift Package Manager to create a macOS executable. When I use things that aren't available in all macOS versions I get compile errors. Two big examples are `URL(fileURLWithPath: filePath, relativeTo: directoryToSearch)` and `url.hasDirectoryPath`.

When building with `swift build` I get `error: 'init(fileURLWithPath:relativeTo:)' is only available on OS X 10.11 or newer` errors. I don't care about any old OS versions, as it's just a personal tool. How can I set the deployment target to be 10.14 so I don't have to sprinkle checks all through out my code?

I found https://hirschmann.io/swift-package-manager/ which talks about this issue. However it's solution is creating an `xcconfig` file with the deployment target set and using `swift package generate-xcodeproj --xcconfig-overrides ./main.xcconfig` to apply it to the generated Xcode project. While it does work, it only works for the Xcode project, so if I just want to do `swift build` to get the free standing executable to use outside of Xcode then I can't.

My package file was auto generated by `swift package init --type executable` and hasn't been changed.

```
// swift-tools-version:4.2
// The swift-tools-version declares the minimum version of Swift required to build this package.

import PackageDescription

let package = Package(
    name: "swift_converter",
    dependencies: [
        // Dependencies declare other packages that this package depends on.
        // .package(url: /* package url */, from: "1.0.0"),
    ],
    targets: [
        // Targets are the basic building blocks of a package. A target can define a module or a test suite.
        // Targets can depend on other targets in this package, and on products in packages which this package depends on.
        .target(
            name: "swift_converter",
            dependencies: []),
        .testTarget(
            name: "swift_converterTests",
            dependencies: ["swift_converter"]),
    ]
)
```

Answer (score 20, accepted):

This may not help you right now, but the upcoming Swift 5.0 will include the ability to [specify the deployment target in the package manifest](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0236-package-manager-platform-deployment-settings.md), using a syntax like this:

```
...
platforms: [
   .macOS(.v10_13), .iOS(.v12),
],
...
```

(The same is true [for some other common build settings](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0238-package-manager-build-settings.md).)

Until then, you can override the default deployment target via command line arguments like this:

```
$ swift build -Xswiftc "-target" -Xswiftc "x86_64-apple-macosx10.14"
```

You'll have to include these arguments in every call to `swift build`, `swift run`, `swift test`.

Comment: Sweet, I am actually using Xcode 10.2b2 so I can use Swift 5.

Comment: Thanks! I had to use `platforms: [.macOS("11.1")]` because when I tried `platforms: [.macOS(.v11_1)]`, I got the build error "reference to member 'v11_1' cannot be resolved without a contextual type". `SupportedPlatform.MacOSVersion.v11_1` doesn't seem to be defined in [`PackageDescription.SupportedPlatform`](https://github.com/apple/swift-package-manager/blob/main/Sources/PackageDescription/SupportedPlatforms.swift) of the version of SwiftPM that comes with Xcode 12.4 (12D4e) (the version and build of Xcode that I'm currently using). For me the latest `MacOSVersion` defined is `v11`.